# Troubleshooting a simple proxy server

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I've written a simple proxy server in C# using synchronous methods and classes of System.Net and System.Net.Sockets. Most of the things are done, except one minor glitch.

When I browse a url from the proxy client (say www.google.com), it opens fine. When I do a keyword search that too goes fine. However, when I click on a search-result, the client again sees the google.com home-page on the screen!! However, the client browser url bar is still showing the search-result url which is clicked.
Perhaps this is happenning because google result page doesn't provide a direct link to the result url, but a link back to google itself, and I think the relay logic in my code is not able to handle that. Could you help me with this? My code is as follows:
(The ThreadHandleClient() method is the important one that handles all the client requests and relays requests and responses)

```
    public void Start(IPAddress ip, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ip, port);
            listener.Start(100);
            while (!stopFlag)
            {
                Socket client = listener.AcceptSocket();
                IPEndPoint rep = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
                Thread th = new Thread(ThreadHandleClient);
                th.Start(client);
            }

            listener.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print("START: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        stopFlag = true;    
    }

    public void ThreadHandleClient(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)o;
            Debug.Print("lingerstate=" + client.LingerState.Enabled.ToString() + " timeout=" + client.LingerState.LingerTime.ToString());
            NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(client);
            //RECEIVE CLIENT DATA
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int rec = 0, sent = 0, transferred = 0, rport = 0;
            string data = "";
            do
            {
                rec = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, rec);
            } while (rec == buffer.Length);

            //PARSE DESTINATION AND SEND REQUEST
            string line = data.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
            Uri uri = new Uri(line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
            Debug.Print("CLIENT REQUEST RECEIVED: " + uri.OriginalString);
            if (uri.Scheme == "https")
            {
                rport = 443;
                Debug.Print("HTTPS - 443");

                //rq = HttpVersion + " 200 Connection established\r\nProxy-Agent: Prahlad`s Proxy Server\r\n\r\n";
                //ClientSocket.BeginSend(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rq), 0, rq.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.OnOkSent), ClientSocket);
            }
            else
            {
                rport = 80;
                Debug.Print("HTTP - 443");
            }
            IPHostEntry rh = Dns.GetHostEntry(uri.Host);
            Socket webserver = new Socket(rh.AddressList[0].AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            webserver.Connect(new IPEndPoint(rh.AddressList[0], rport));
            byte[] databytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            webserver.Send(databytes, databytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            Debug.Print("SENT TO SERVER. WILL NOW RELAY: " + data);

            //START RELAY
            buffer = new byte[2048];
            bool firstTime = true;
            rec = 0;
            data = "";
            do
            {
                transferred = 0;
                do
                {
                    if (webserver.Poll((firstTime ? 9000 : 2000) * 1000, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                    {
                        rec = webserver.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        Debug.Print("RECEIVED FROM WEBSERVER[" + rec.ToString() + "]: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, rec));
                        firstTime = false;
                        sent = client.Send(buffer, rec, SocketFlags.None);
                        Debug.Print("SENT TO CLIENT[" + sent.ToString() + "]: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, rec));
                        transferred += rec;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Print("No data polled from webserver");
                    }
                } while (rec == buffer.Length);

                Debug.Print("loop-1 finished");

                //if (transferred == 0)
                //     break;

                //transferred = 0;
                rec = 0;
                do
                {
                    if (client.Poll(1000 * 1000, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                    {
                        rec = client.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        Debug.Print("RECEIVED FROM CLIENT: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, rec));

                        sent = webserver.Send(buffer, rec, SocketFlags.None);
                        Debug.Print("SENT TO WEBSERVER[" + sent.ToString() + "]: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, rec));
                        transferred += rec;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Print("No data polled from client");
                    }
                } while (rec == buffer.Length);
                Debug.Print("loop-2 finished");

            } while (transferred > 0);
            Debug.Print("LOOP ENDS. EXITING THREAD");
            client.Close();
            webserver.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print("Error occured: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally {
            Debug.Print("Client thread closed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the solution, hence I'm answering my own question. The issue with my relay logic was that it used to relay both ways i.e. from webserver->client and client->webserver. 
I realized that relaying the second part could lead to trouble in redirects, because in redirects the url part of the header ("GET http://debian.org HTTP/1.1") would suddenly change, so that it will be different from the web-server being relayed!! For example, the google redirect pointed to debian.org, whereas the proxy will still relay traffic from google.com and not debian.org.
To avoid this situation, I removed the second relay part (i.e. client->webserver). If a clients sends a new request, it better be handled in a separate thread, so that it would be directed to the proper url host. So, all I had to do was comment out the second inner loop in my relay logic:

```
                //rec = 0;
                //do
                //{
                //    if (client.Poll(3000 * 1000, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                //    {
                //        rec = client.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                //        Debug.Print("RECEIVED FROM CLIENT: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, rec));

                //        sent = webserver.Send(buffer, rec, SocketFlags.None);
                //        Debug.Print("SENT TO WEBSERVER[" + sent.ToString() + "]: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, rec));
                //        transferred += rec;
                //    }
                //    else
                //    {
                //        Debug.Print("No data polled from client");
                //    }
                //} while (rec == buffer.Length);
                //Debug.Print("loop-2 finished");
```